# add text of a tag to input tag by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, input, tags

I want to show information to submit or reject.
I have a tag() include the information that should be checked.
if some of them are not correct, should be added to input tag and then by click on reject button, all input tag data pass to controller.
The following code does not work.
I dont know is there a better way to do it ?
thanks a lot for your attention.

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>example</title>

    <link href="@Url.Content("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.css")" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="@Url.Content("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.js")"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" data-value="1">Name</a>
    <div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto;">
        <h2 style="font-family:cursive;">Jquery - input tags plugin example</h2>
        <input name="tags" id="input-tags" style="width:500px !important" />
    </div>
    <script>
        $("a").click(function () {
        i = $(this).data("value");
  $('#input-tags').tagsInput('add', i);

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more detailed description of  your issue. This is not very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `jQuery TagsInput` not `Bootstrap TagsInput` so you should use `addTag` not `.tagsInput('add')`

```js
$('#input-tags').tagsInput();

$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var i = $(this).data("value");
  $('#input-tags').addTag(i);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-value="1">Name</a>
<div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto;">
  <h2 style="font-family:cursive;">Jquery - input tags plugin example</h2>
  <input name="tags" id="input-tags" data_role="tagsinput" style="width:500px !important" />
</div>
```

**[Source](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input)**

Comment: thanks a lot for your correct answer. how can i pass input tag data to controller?

Comment: @user3639362 Your welcome. Sorry I am not expert in `asp.net` , I recommend you to create new question for this.

Comment: ok, your right. i create new question. in my program when i click on tag a go to link by # at end of that and does not add to input tags, can you help me please?

Comment: @user3639362 If `#` in anchor tag annoying you, use `e.preventDefault();` check out the updated answer.

Comment: tnx.thats ok but now by clicking on anchor tag anything add to input tag .

Comment: @user3639362 anything? like what? similar to my answer it should add only `data-value` value.

Comment: anything, i run your snippet and its ok but when i click on my anchor tag in my program nothing happen,i test th js code when i run only tagsinput() it works well but i think addtag does not work

Comment: @user3639362 After clicking, do you have error on browser console log?

Comment: So, are you saying, after add `e.preventDefault();` it stop working? If yes, you can use another solution to prevent `#` on URL.

Comment: yes, but before use  e.preventDefault(); it does not work too becuase it navigate to url with the end of #

Comment: @user3639362 You can do: **1.** remove `href` tag at all, you don't need it. **2.**  or use `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of `#`

Comment: tnx a lot for your attention. the reason is the program is  not understanding of jquery.tagsinput.min.js .